# What <realize> means here

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I found out her name was Sera.

I might have heard from others / I might have googled her. So I became aware of it.

> 2. I figured out her name was Sera.

I might have been keep trying to remember her name in my mind / Someone might have told me some hints about her name and I made it.

> 3. I noticed her name was Sera.

I might have seen her name was written somewhere.

> 4. I knew her name was Sera.

I just knew.

> 5. I realized her name was Sera.

I don't know what this means.....

Can you help me with this?

Comment: When you suddenly know that the thing is the key to solve the puzzle that has been in your mind for a while then that is when you **realize** it.

Comment: Remembering her name is not to **figure it out**.

Answer (score 1):

If she has a monogram on her backpack or brief case, and there are only two students on the class list or two employees on the company roster with those initials, and one of them is a guy, you can **figure out** her name.

When you **realize** something, you are aware of it:

> I realize that you have another meeting at 2PM, so we'll keep this meeting
>   brief.

or you come to be aware of it:

> When the smoke alarm went off, I suddenly realized that I'd forgotten to turn off the frying pan.